# Generalization of $F=mv\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{m}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(v^2)$ to 3-dimensions in a compact notation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, notation, differentiation

Starting from $F=ma=m\frac{dv}{dt}$, in 1-dimension, it is easy to show that $$F=mv\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{m}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(v^2).\tag{1}$$ Can we generalize this formula in 3-dimensions? In 3D, $$\textbf{F}=m\frac{d\textbf{v}}{dt}$$ $$\Rightarrow \textbf{F}=m\Big[\frac{\partial\textbf{v}}{\partial x}\dot{x}+\frac{\partial\textbf{v}}{\partial y}\dot{y}+\frac{\partial\textbf{v}}{\partial z}\dot{z}\Big]\tag{2}$$

Is it possible to write (2) in a more compact notation using vector identities?

Comment: If you want to get super fancy, you can write this in relativity-style index notation as $F^a=m\dot{r}^b\partial_b v^a $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this written in hydrodynamics as $$\vec{F} = m \left (\vec {v}\cdot\nabla\right)\vec{v} $$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. And then you can rewrite it to 1/2 grad (v^2) + (curl v) x v (with 'x' the cross product). This is probably as close as possible in 3d to the original question

Comment: *This does not really answer the question.* Huh? It does answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no (from what I know). At higher dimensions the $v\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}$ term gets replaced by terms like $v_y\frac{\partial{v_x}}{\partial{y}}$

For example, you can see that the x-component of the force is

$ F_x =  m \left( \frac{\partial{v_x}}{\partial{x}}v_{x} + 
\frac{\partial{v_x}}{\partial{y}}v_{y} + 
\frac{\partial{v_x}}{\partial{z}}v_{z} \right )$

You could write this in matrix form, however.